# Solve the differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \cos(x+y) + \sin(x+y)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem:**

> Solve the differential equation,$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} 
>  =\cos(x+y) + \sin(x+y)$$

**My attempt at the problem:**

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} 
 =\cos(x+y) + \sin(x+y)=\cos(x+y)\biggr(1+\tan(x+y)\biggr)$$

Now let, $$\cos(x+y)=u$$

So that,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} 
 = u(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}-1})$$
using    $\tan^2A = \sec^2A - 1$

Also,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(\cos(x+y))}{\mathrm{d}x} 
 = -\sin(x+y)\biggr(1 + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \biggr) $$

and
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} 
 = -\sqrt{1-u^2}\biggr(1 + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \biggr)$$

Solving for $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and plugging it in the problem gives a very ugly integral upon separating variables

$$\int{\mathrm{d}x} = - \int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\biggr((u+1)+\sqrt{1-u^2}\biggr)\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

I just can't solve it any further.

Please correct me if I'm wrong or please direct me towards an alternate solution. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

set $$x+y=u$$ then we have $$y=u-x$$ and $$y'=u'-1$$ and we have
$$u'-1=\cos(u)+\sin(u)$$
Can you solve this?

Comment: you have made $$\cos(x+y)=u$$ and i have Substitute $$x+y=u$$ there is a difference

Comment: Can *you* solve it, Dr. Graubner?

Comment: the solution is very big!

Comment: @TobErnack The left-hand side is $u'-1$ and not $u'$, right?

Comment: @mickep Oops you are right... That does make it more complicated unfortunately. I still think the integral is solvable using a trick like $t = \tan(u/2)$ but then it's also probably easy enough to do that from $\cos(u) + \sin(u)$.

Comment: @TobErnack Indeed, but the primitive actually looks simpler, since $\int 1/(1+\cos u+\sin u)\,du$ becomes $\ln(1+\tan(u/2))$ or something similar.

Comment: @mickep sorry for the late reply. This is exactly the answer! Can you just put it in the form of an answer?

Comment: Since the only missing piece from the excellent answer of @Dr.SonnhardGraubner is the $t=\tan(u/2)$ substitution, I suggest that I do not add another answer with only that detail.